# Struts to spring migration getting 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
/spring/fetchAllUsers URL which am trying

web.xml
  <servlet>
            <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:springContext/dataSource.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/spring/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        Controller Code
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional(propagation=Propogation.REQUIRED,rollBackFor=Exception.class)
public String fetchAllUsers(){
setInputStream(userDelegate.fetchAllUsers());
return success;
```

Details:
        And I have mvc annotation driven and mvc default servlet handler in user-servlet.xml

```
    Getting 404 error code when try to access this URl when doing migration from struts to spring
```

Break point is not hit when this URL is hit and no errors in console as well.Please suggest on the above issue

Comment: You will have some difficulties to understand Spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

since your servlet url mapping has already include /spring you don't need to include it in @RequestMapping.

try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but still am getting 404 for the request.So I tried for another method call fetchAllUsers as above which is also showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

According to your servlet mapping only one url is allowed `localhost:8080/context/spring/` that is not mapped with your controller.

When we defined a servlet-mapping, we are using **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping**. To understand servlet url mapping let define a servlet mapping :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now the handler will actually use the * part to find the controller. It will not search /spring/createUser, it will only search for /createUser to find a corresponding Controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/createUser")
```

In your case You need to either change your url to `localhost:8080/spring/spring/createUser` or remove prefix from Controller `@RequestingMapping(/createUser)`.

Comment: Still getting 404 for theabove data.But now am not getting any servlet error

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but still am getting 404 for the request.So I tried for another method call fetchAllUsers as above which is also showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Spring interprets urls `/spring/createUser/` and `/spring/createUser` differently(*atleast in `POST` methods that i just tested*).

Change your `@RequestMapping` url to `/spring/createUser`.

Also mind that the url you call is `/spring/createUser` without a trailing slash("**/**").

Your method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spring/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but still am getting 404 for the request.So I tried for another method call fetchAllUsers as above which is also showing the same error